# Definition of a tree and 2 cycles

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hamiltonian-path

I've run into a problem with the definition of a tree, and possibly more generally with the definition of a cycle.  I've run into the problem a few sections after we talked about trees, and I never really thought of the problem until I got into Hamiltonian cycles.  I will state my problem in three steps:
1.  Fact: the complete graph on 2 vertices is Hamiltonian and so contains a cycle.
2.  Fact: a tree is a connected acyclic graph.
3.  Therefore, since every tree besides the trivial tree contains K2 as a subgraph, there exist no trees.

Now, obviously something is missing in the details.  My book clearly states the definition of a tree as a connected acyclic graph.  So, is it not the case that K2 is Hamiltonian?  Is there no such thing as a 2-cycle?

Is my definition of a tree not adequate?  Does it exclude 2 cycles from the necessity of there not being a cycle in the graph?

Please, someone help me to clear this up.

Comment: The complete graph on 2 vertices might be represented by an infinite tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of *tree* is fine. Partly to avoid this difficulty, [by convention $K_2$ is not considered to be Hamiltonian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html).

Comment: see, but this screws me up.  For homework, i recently had to prove that the n-cube is hamiltonian.  My proof relied on the fact that $Q_2$ is Hamiltonian and that the cartesian product of two Hamiltonian graphs is Hamiltonian.  I suppose my proof is crap now.  Oh well...

Comment: @user3440448: You can fix it without too much trouble: you just need to prove that if $G$ is Hamiltonian, so is the product of $G$ with $K_2$, and that’s not hard: traverse all but the last step of a Hamilton cycle in one copy of $G$, move to the other copy, trace the same cycle backwards, and return to your starting point.

Comment: Right, and that was actually my initial idea until i thought "hey! isn't $Q_2$ Hamiltonian!"  Unfortunately, the mistake has been made and handed in.  Thank you for your input on this matter.

Comment: @user3440448: You’re welcome. (I suspected that was the case. For what it’s worth, I’d give significant partial credit for that answer.)